# Why does ethereum JSON RPC encode bytes as hex?

Tags: json-rpc, hex

Why not use base64 since it would be more compact?

Comment: Here https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#hex-value-encoding it talks about hex encoding, however, doesn't exactly talk about why take a look at it.

Comment: Their use of json-rpc doesn't appear to suggest they were trying to optimize for size. There is already the p2p protocol which is binary. You can always use json-rpc over another protocol like http+gzip.

Comment: @balajipachai I'm really looking for the why!

Comment: @Ismael I'm wondering, what were they optimising for? Clearly not ease of development :)

Comment: @PiersyP They wanted to launch the ethereum network as main objective. The initial protocol had the minimal functionality to be useful. They sometimes add new methods.

Comment: @ismael The thing is, its more work to encode stuff in hex, because by default most JSON marshalling libraries will encode bytes as base64. So it would have been more minimal to encode bytes as base64.